# Header of Stack Overflow question is wrapped with <a> tag and href is current page

Tags: discussion, design, title

When you go to any question and information, then you find the title of the question is wrapped in an <a> tag, and its link is redirected back to the current page. Is this <a> tag is useful or not, because sometimes when I want to copy some text of the title, then this <a> tag prevents to copy?

Sometimes it just looks like a page refresh link and it annoys me.

This is a little issue, but it still needs to be considered.

Comment: When you want to copy (part of) the link text, hold the Alt key and then select the text.

Comment: @Stijn: what is that "Alt key" you speak of on my iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say yes, this is useful.

1. It's consistent UI design: the title of the question is always a link to the question, wherever you find it.
2. It makes it easy to copy a *general* link to the question (in contrast to the user-specific link *share* leads to).
3. Depending on the browser, it facilitates easy copying of the whole title

   Chrome and Firefox have a *Copy link text* function on right click/long press of a hyperlink. That saves you from needing to select specific text. Chrome accounts for 60-70% of browser market share.

Most UI design choices have both advantages and disadvantages, I think the advantages outweigh the disadvantages on this one.

Comment: It also facilitates an easy refresh, now that many windows laptop default keyboards require you to use the function button to get at the f-keys, it can be easier to click than to hit f-5.

Comment: Chrome doesn't have the "Copy link text" function and AFAIK [it never had](https://crbug.com/11783). There are extensions though.

Comment: @wOxxOmw I'm using mobile chrome right now and it has that. Desktop chrome does not though.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth Thanks, but is there any way to copy some of the text from the title? I mean if I want to copy 'Stack Overflow question' from the above title, what is the way to copy? By the way, I am using chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.